# C++ How To open an application using Text Input and If Statements

Tags: c++, windows, c++11

I'm trying to make a simple application launcher using C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int textin;
cin >> textin;
if ( textin == "ATLauncher" )
    {
    system("C:\\Users\\NAME\\Main\\minecraftlaunchers\\AtLauncher\\ATLauncher.exe");
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
    }
}
```

Error msgs that appear when using Dev C++

> [Error] ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Comment: What do you mean by "not get it to work"? Error message? Segfault? Does it compile?

Comment: Your question seems to be specific to Windows. So please edit it and tag it as such. (On Linux or POSIX systems the `<windows.h>` header file does not exist).

Comment: What's your question? Besides "can anyone help", that is

Comment: _"I'm not used to StackOverFlows formatting so the code may seam 'messed up'"_ That's why there is a preview pane, so you can see and fix any formatting problems before you post. Thus, being new to the site is irrelevant: you simply keep working on the post until it is complete. For what it's worth, you did an okay job with the formatting here.

Comment: You have a warning that says: line 10: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer.   Is this error message confusing?  Perhaps the better question is "what does this error message mean?" I think being able to understand error messages is more important than fixing this little problem.

Comment: You use `std::string textin;` instead of `int textin;` that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

system() is one possible std lib call to start a command (see also spawn, exec ...)
you don't quite need to run pause as system should not return until the first command is completed

in your string \ should be \ \x mean special character x ie \n (new line)

Answer (score 1):

Problems I've found in your code:

`textin` was declared as `int`, but you compare it to a string literal (`"ATLauncher"`). Change the type of `textin` to `std::string` (and include the header `<string>`).

The backslash (`\`) is a escape character in strings in C/C++. In order to place a real backslashes, use `\\` for each `\`.

Some other observations:

`system` is declared in `<stdlib.h>`, not in `<windows.h>`.

The `system("pause")` doesn't have to be there. It will just make you have to press some key after the program lauched terminates to close the console.

Comment: How do i change the "Type" of textin to std:string?